# send numpy array as an argument inside python eval() function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable that gets the name of the function that I wish to call, `function_name = "some_func"`.
I used the `eval()` function and it worked when the parameters were `int`, `list` etc. But when I tried that with numpy arrays(`np.ndarray`), error pops up.

Probably the numpy array gets converted into string and I get an error:

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np 

def some_func(np_arr):
    print(np_arr)
    print(type(np_arr))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    function_name = "some_func"
    my_arr = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
    eval(f"{function_name}({my_arr})")
    my_np_arr = np.array(my_arr)
    print(type(my_np_arr))

    #The line below doesn't work
    eval(f"{function_name}({my_np_arr})")
```

**Error Message:**

```
  eval(f"{function_name}({my_np_arr})")
  File "<string>", line 1
    some_func([[1 1 1]
                ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

How do I send the variable `my_np_arr` *(numpy array)* inside the eval function as a parameter?

Comment: Don't use `eval`. Consider using a lookup table instead, E.g. `{"some_func": some_func}[function_name](my_np_arr)`.

Comment: I believe np arrays don't have commas when printed.  @DanielB has the better solution

Comment: "[1 2 3]", the `str` display format of an array cannot be `eval`.  Only "np.array([1,2,3])" `evals` correctly.  In contrast the string '[1,2,3]' does eval as a list.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, `eval` is not a good idea. (And neither is `exec`.) If you just want to execute a function you pass to another function, you can pass functions around like any other objects. So `def run_func(f, arg): return f(arg)` is totally valid. In other words: you don't need to pass the function name as a string.

Comment: For this kind of thing, passing `arr.tolist()` is easier than any special games with formatting and evaluating an array.